# Print rows in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

Here is a sample of my csv file:

```
1   Ryan    Giggs   £13.50  23  Manchester  Utd
2   David   Beckham £40.00  24  Manchester  Utd
3   Michael Owen    £22.00  22  Liverpool
4   Robbie  Fowler  £21.00  23  Leeds Utd
```

I have written this code with the intent to print out the first row:

```
import csv

with open("Footballers.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[1])
```

However this only print out the first(technically second) column like so:

```
Ryan
David
Micheal
Robbie
```

How can I make it print out the first row like so?

```
1 Ryan Giggs £13.50 23 Manchester Utd
```

Comment: @roganjosh That would print all the rows, the asker only want the first one.

Comment: @roganjosh I did the same when I first replied to the question

Comment: @roganjosh Why setup a for loop if you only need one item. That's what `next` does. Besides the `for` loop is itself calling `next` behind the scenes.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye exactly why I suggested "or pick one of the _more_ _elegant_ solutions". I had already seen your answer and it was explained better than one I could squish in a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`row[1]` gives the 2nd thing in `row` (because it starts counting at 0). You want all of `row`, separated by spaces. You can replace `row[1]` with `" ".join(row)` to fix it. `" "` is the thing we want each item to be separated by, and `row` is the list we want to separate.

The full code would be

```
import csv

with open("Footballers.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(" ".join(row))
```

Comment: Your code will print every rows.

Answer (score 7):

Drop the for loop and use `next` if you only intend to print the first row, as the `for` iterates on the object and will successively supply each row:

```
with open("Footballers.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print(next(reader)[0]) # default separator is a comma so you only get one item in the row
```

The `reader` object is an iterator and calling `next` on it will provide the *next* item which in this case is the first row. Note that this advances the iterator and subsequent iterations on it will start from the second row.

Answer (score 2):

Use join

```
import csv

with open("Footballers.csv") as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   for row in reader:
   print(' '.join(row) )
```

Comment: Each row is a list with only item, because the default separator is a comma. Calling `join` is probably not needed

Comment: Can you elaborate?